# C# Web Form button size change when running from different OS

Tags: c#, webforms

I can not figure out why my web form buttons change size when I run the web form from Windows 7 vs. Windows Server 2003.  I have set the positioning and size on page load for all objects.  Here is an example of a couple of the objects I am using.

```
Label1.Style.Add("Position", "fixed");
Label1.Style.Add("TOP", "20px");
Label1.Style.Add("Left", "50px");

btnQuery.Style.Add("Position", "fixed");
btnQuery.Style.Add("TOP", "370px");
btnQuery.Style.Add("Left", "198px");
```

The buttons have the same 3 entries.  When I run this from my local Windows 7 PC, everything looks great.  However, when I publish this to my Server 2003 site, the buttons are about 5 times longer and cover each other up.  My label, textbox, and listbox are all fine as well.  It is just the buttons.  Is it because I am developing on Windows 7?  Also, I am doing this in Visual Studio 2010, Framework 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only setting the top/left position of the button, but not the size...  If not specified, then web browsers are free to make buttons look however they want.

Assuming that this Style.Add method actually translates to CSS, try adding:

```
btnQuery.Style.Add("height", "120px");
btnQuery.Style.Add("width", "300px");
```

Then tweak those so its the size you want.

Generally, I'd advise against using fixed positioning at all, but that is a different story.

Answer (score 2):

They are changing because you are giving the size in pixels. If users have different screen resolutions, then it will change how large the buttons are in relation to the screen. Use relative sizing to fix this. This is not OS dependent, may just seem like it.